# log4j appender to save log as json format with additional data

Tags: json, spring, log4j2

I am trying to figure out the best way to write all of our logs as a single line of `JSON` using `log4j2`. Can any one suggest me appender to achieve above one. Any help would be appreciated. Currently I am converting data into `JSON` and logging at particular levels but I want to do it automatically.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout)?

Comment: can you show what you have so far and an example of how you want it to look

Comment: yah i read that one implementing that one

Comment: And also i need to thread local values automatically